# Django OneToOneField not creating table

Tags: mysql, django, database

Thanks in advance, that.s my users/models.py file :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} profile".format(self.user.username)
```

Then I run python manage.py makemigrations + python manage.py migrate, everything seems to works fine but it doesn't create a table users_profile :

> 1146, "Table 'polls_db.users_profile' doesn't exist")
> in the admin section + same when i try to manipulate profile threw the shell.

I checked my mariadb database and there is indeed no users_profile table.

I'm still learning django and it worked fine in a previous project with an sqlite database, is there a solution ?

EDIT : when Switching to the default sqlite3 data base users_profile is automatically created although i'm facing another problem with the sqlite3 databse this time it doesn't want to create a column named popularity :

```
Class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True)
    question_text = models.CharField("Question", max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        "date de publication", default=timezone.now )
    popularity = models.IntegerField("popularité", default=0)
```

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: table polls_question has no column
> named popularity

EDIT 2 : Installed PostgreSQL and everything is working, users_profile got automatically created and no issues with others models like i experienced with sqlite3, that's not a solution but just wanted to let you know

Comment: Have you added the users app in settings inside INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes of course sir, here is the INSTALLED_APPS section of mysite/mysite/settings.py INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: Once you did python `manage.py makemigrations` did the migrations file create itself in the migrations folder of your app?

Comment: I've deleted everything and restarded from scratch and still the same, yes it creates a migration folder + files, shell output after makemigrations : Migrations for 'users':
  users/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Profile
,Still nothing in the mysql database

Comment: Is it going to work if i directly create the table in mariadb without django ?

Comment: The `user` attribute of your `Profile` model isn't properly indented. Can you confirm that the same mistake hasn't occurred in your `users/models.py` file?

Comment: it's correctly indented, just struggled here with copy/paste, btw it worked directly when limking the default sqlite3 db instead of mariadb so apparently no code error

Comment: what all rows of data do you have in your maria db table called `django_migrations`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2vWVELHB last is from 18/06

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors in this code. Try to change the database to SQLite and see if the error still occurs maybe its problem with database setting

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the mariadb databse by the defaut sqlite3 one and yes it has created users_profile, is it a known error with mysql ? I would want to keep using it

my settings.py DATABASES if it could helps :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'polls_db',
        'USER': os.environ.get("MYSQL_U"),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("MYSQL_P"),
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': "",
    }


}
```

Comment: What versions of Django and MariaDB are you using?

Comment: Django 3.0 and mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.13-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1, should be latest i'm running on arch ( or maybe that's the problem lol )